# core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'TwitterAuthProvider' of undefined

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

```
   var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
  firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
    // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
    // var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // var secret = result.credential.secret;
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    console.log(user);
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
  });
```

I am getting
**core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'TwitterAuthProvider' of undefined**
error while running the application

Comment: The error is suggesting that `firebase.auth` is undefined.  Please edit the question to show how you are importing the Firebase Auth SDK.  You might need to go back and follow the instructions for getting started with the SDK again.

Comment: ```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
```this is how i added @DougStevenson

Comment: Can you help to howto set auth for firebase providers